GnuPG only returns false
I want to use gpg in PHP but it only returns false. Can anyone help me?
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$publicKey = file_get_contents('test.asc');

$gpg=gnupg_init();
$PublicData = $publicKey;
$res=gnupg_import($gpg, $PublicData);
var_dump($res); -- returns false
$er=gnupg_geterror($gpg);
var_dump($er); --returns false

?>    


That's my complete code, anyone see something wrong? It would be nice if anyone had a fix.
Thank you.
I want that PGP encryption and decryption work and not just return false.

Try the advice in this comment ~ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-import.php#126304

@Phil you are a genius
